# What is ClientVersionNotSupportedError and how to resolve it

Tags: cadence-workflow

This QA is from a Slack conversation: https://uber-cadence.slack.com/archives/CL22WDF70/p1625155376151600

Using local CLI, version 0.18.4; the Cadence server is version 0.16.0.  The CLI works for some operations, such as cadence wf describe/cancel fails:

```
$ cadence wf cancel -w 'FbrEngineController(clirId=76351141)'
Error: Cancel workflow failed.
Error Details: ClientVersionNotSupportedError{FeatureVersion: 1.7.0, ClientImpl: cli, SupportedVersions: <=1.6.0}
('export CADENCE_CLI_SHOW_STACKS=1' to see stack traces)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Client version checking is a feature to prevent using new clients/CLI against old server.
You will only enable `EnableClientVersionCheck` dynamic config on the server. By default it's disabled.

But if you already intend to use new clients/CLI against older server, you don't have to use this feature. Nothing will go seriously wrong, server will just return error it some request can't be supported.

For example, all the information about [0.16 server/CLI is here](https://github.com/uber/cadence/blob/v0.16.0/common/client/versionChecker.go),
it supports CLI version up to 0.16.

And if you check

```
https://github.com/uber/cadence/blob/v0.12.0/common/client/versionChecker.go
https://github.com/uber/cadence/blob/v0.13.0/common/client/versionChecker.go
https://github.com/uber/cadence/blob/v0.14.0/common/client/versionChecker.go
https://github.com/uber/cadence/blob/v0.15.0/common/client/versionChecker.go
https://github.com/uber/cadence/blob/v0.16.0/common/client/versionChecker.go
https://github.com/uber/cadence/blob/v0.17.0/common/client/versionChecker.go
https://github.com/uber/cadence/blob/v0.18.0/common/client/versionChecker.go
https://github.com/uber/cadence/blob/v0.19.0/common/client/versionChecker.go
and
https://github.com/uber/cadence/blob/v0.20.0/common/client/versionChecker.go
```

They all support CLI version 0.16.

But the latest [release (0.21) support up to 0.17](https://github.com/uber/cadence/blob/v0.21.3/common/client/versionChecker.go) as this CLI version is bumped at 0.21.

Therefore CLI of 0.20 can work against server of 0.12 ~ 0.20

The oldest cadence homebrew is 0.18.2: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/commits/master/Formula/cadence-workflow.rb

So if you are using an old version of Cadence server(0.12-0.20) and want to [use Cadence CLI via homebrew](https://github.com/uber/cadence/discussions/4457), then downgrade it to the older version.